# How to switch between to value from switch input?

Tags: html, laravel

I have this input button: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNwzI.png)

The code of input:

```
<div class="media">
 <label class="col-form-label m-r-10">Status Of System</label>
 <div class="media-body text-right icon-state">
 <label class="switch">
  <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      name="status" 
      value="{{ setting()->status == '1' ? 0 : 1 }}"
  >
  <span class="switch-state bg-primary"></span>
</label>
```

the setting()->status is helper function:

```
 if (! function_exists('setting') ) {
    function setting(){
      return \App\Setting::first();
  }
}
```

And in the column(status), the default is 1.

The problem is when I try to switch between `1` and `0`. Notice value attribute in input I try to say if the column in database 1 put 0 else put 1 to switch the value, but this way does not run find! How can do something like this :(

Comment: try to print json_encode of setting() and post what is return, or at least, the "status" value

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia once give me the value=0 and when I turn off the button does not give me anything in dd()

Comment: maybe it's a problem on how you update the value instead on how you put that value on the form

Comment: you mean your value isn't switching? then show code how you switch it. i assume it is `update` button

Comment: setting()->update($request->all());

Comment: yeah, of course, it's update in the controller like above

Comment: i understood. i've updated my answer, take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, try like that:

Check checkbox according setting value:

```html
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="status" 
    @if(1 === setting()->status) checked @endif
>
```

Here you retrieved `status` from database. If it exists and exactly equals `1`, checkbox will be checked. If not - unchecked.

Next you want to change database value according this checkbox `checked` state.

Checkbox field appears in `$request` only if checkbox checked. So, try to refactor a bit your controller:

```php
$setting = \App\Setting::first(); // your setting
$setting->status = isset($request->status) ? 1 : 0; // if status exists in request, it means that checkbox was checked
$setting->save(); // update your database row
```

Comment: No No, I know how to make the input checked. the problem when I switch the value to the database from 1 to 0 and vice versa.

Comment: you are right, just keep in mind that he want the inverse, so it should be 0 === setting()->status

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia same thing! :(

Comment: Roman Man! your code works!  can you pls explain the code! pls

Comment: i've updated my answer, explained as detailed as possible

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just one:

when a checkbox isn't checked, it's value isn't inserted in the request. So you have to check before the update if that checkbox value exist.

So instead of

```
setting()->update($request->all());
```

you have to do

```
$params = $request->all();
if(!isset($params['status'])) $params['status'] = 1;
setting()->update($params);
```

Also on the internet there is another solution, which is to add a `hidden` input with the same `name` and with the value that you want if that checkbox isn't checked like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="1">
```

But in my opinion, it's just a dirty workaround... but you can have a try

Comment: Undefined index: status

Comment: i assume, you have to use `isset` instead of just `!`

Comment: this line :  if(!$params['status'])

Comment: the same old one does not switch the value!  now in the database, the column is 1 but when I try to switch button to make it 0 stays 1

Comment: which solution of the 2 are you using? you should choose just one of the two

Comment: please, combine mine and @RomanBobrik answers... add also the checked when the status is 0

Comment: $params = $request->all();

        if( setting()->status === 1){

            $params['status'] = 0;

        }elseif(setting()->status === 0){
            
            $params['status'] = 1;

        }

Comment: then mark please one of answers as correct, to close this question

Comment: mmm this will switch the value each time

Comment: which way? what was the problem with mine solution? i mean, what's the wrong behavior ?

Comment: I see if I have three or four buttons like that it will be weird!

Comment: Your way the value does not switch into 0, it just stays 1 in database

Comment: so, starting from 0, than you can switch to 1, but can't then come back to 0? please, after having set the value to 1, check which value is printed inside 'value="" ' in the checkbox